# How do I recover my username and password on a persistent LiveUSB?

Tags: 11.04, login, live-usb

I booted Ubuntu 11.04 from a persistent pendrive installation. It asked for the keyring password the 1st time, and I just cancelled the dialog window and went through. After the 3rd or 4th booting (keyring window did not appear anymore), a window with "automatic log in" (which does not work) and "other" tab choices appear. "Other" prompts me to give "user" name and "password" and the problem is that I never set up these.

I have already tried to get to a root command window on recovery mode at booting as per some forum instructions. I could never get recovery mode; the system said: `no image on kernel` or something like that. I reinstalled Ubuntu and fell in the same trap again. Need help. Please accept my thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

For the live cd (and media made from the cd) the username is 'ubuntu' and the password is blank - just hit enter when asked for a password.

That will work unless you have changed the password or created another user, which I understand that you have not.